# I can't get how to use JSON, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I saw a lot of questions and examples of using JSON, i understand  "parse" and "stringify" methods, but i still can't use it.

From previous homework I have a code of images gallery, the links to images are hard coded there.
Now i need to use a JSON file to upload pics, i know how to add different parameters to object, like "className" and "src", but it's not very helpful in my situation.

Here is my old HTML code:

```
<li>
<a href="#image-9">
  <img src="images/thumbs/9.jpg" alt="image09">
  <span>Arabesque</span>
</a>
<div class="lb-overlay" id="image-9">
  <img src="images/full/9.jpg" alt="image09" />
  <div>                         
    <h3>Some text</h3>
    <p>More text</p>
    <a href="#image-8" class="lb-prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#image-10" class="lb-next">Next</a>
</div>
<a href="#page" class="lb-close">x Close</a>
</div>
</li>
```

Here is my JSON's file structure:

```
var photos =  [
{
    "title": "Caterpillar_Butterfly",
    "img_thumb": "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3024/3036341686_2a4cc2d8cd_q.jpg",
    "img_src": "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3024/3036341686_4138dfbecc_o.jpg",
    "tags": "butterfly quote caterpillar wisdom quotation masterton henleylake sirwiseowl"
},
```

Can you give me advice or any kind of help? How i can implement it?
Thank you guys!

Comment: `photos[0]["title"]` will print `"Caterpillar_Butterfly"`

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: _JSON_ is just a string which is "safe" to be passed around. Once you've `parse`d it, work with it exactly the same as any other _Object_. Remember that _JSON_ will be valid _JavaScript_ so if you're writing it directly in code you have actually written an _Object_ literal.

Comment: i am trying to delete all hard coded images, and use only JSON file to show images. The problem is that this gallery is implemented like lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you will want to write a Javascript program such as inside `<script> .. do stuff here </script>` tags inside the `<head></head>` section that takes the information and does the task.  JSON is a way of storing information down, Javascript is what actually does the work.

Comment: ok, i get the picture from file, then i did: img.src = bla", img.id = bla. Now i have ready object, but how i should add it to my div in html? ok, i will rephrase my question. If i will do document.getElementById.appendChild(img) is it will be same as my old html code? I am trying to do it this way, but I can't get the result.